# search keywords and ignore keywords from datafeed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation where I need to match products in my database with products coming in from a datafeed.

The datafeed has a product-name column.

While my database table has KEYWORDS and IGNORE_KEYWORDS columns.

Matching should be such that if **ALL** db KEYWORDS match the datafeed product-name AND **NONE** of the db IGNORE_KEYWORDS match the datafeed product-name, then it is a positive match.

For e.g.

```
Datafeed:

ID, Name, Url, ...
1, iPhone 5s 64GB Unlocked 1 year warranty, http://....
2, iPhone 5s 64GB Locked O2 2 years Deal, http://....

Database:
ID, KEYWORDS, IGNORE_KEYWORDS, ...
1000, iPhone 5s 64GB, Locked, ...
1001, iPhone 5s 64GB, Unlocked, ...
```

Now when I match, it should match:

```
Datafeed #1 to Database #1000
Datafeed #2 to Database #1001
```

The problem is that matching ALL KEYWORDS from database column in the datafeed product-name would be difficult using a direct query. I dont think it is even possible! But may be there is some direct method to do this.

And if not a direct method, then could there be an indirect method? Like creating another table to hold keywords and ids of database original table?

**What is the fastest and most optimized method to do this kind of matching?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way to do this is to move the keywords in a separate table, one keyword per row. Then you'd be able to perform queries on them. Won't be possible with a single query, but at least it will be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is important here is that ALL keywords for a particular product do match for a single datafeed product name. So if for eg. `iPhone-1000` and `5s-1000` are matched but `64GB-1000` is not matched, then it means the product ID `1000` did not match. How do we do that?

Comment: I guess this kind of matching would require a distinct check and a having count(*) test to verify that all keywords of the product have matched??? Any easy way to do this?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_keywords WHERE value IN ('iPhone-1000', '5s-1000', ' 64GB-1000')` then you'd check if the count is 3.

Comment: I guess it should be something like: `SELECT count(*), id FROM my_keywords WHERE keyword IN ('iPhone', '5s', '64GB') GROUP BY id`. So this will return all product ids with counts and we pick those that matched all the 3 right? I guess this would work if our keywords and search words are made sure to be unique.

Comment: I have built a new table for ID-KEYWORD mapping and ID-IGNORE_KEYWORD mapping. The matching for ignore keyword is easy, but the matching for keyword is quite difficult still. If there are mappings of 10000 products in the keywords table, with each product having 3 to 4 keywords, then how can I use a single query to find out that ALL the keywords of a particular product has matched?

Comment: I guess one method is to also save the total keywords count in the table. Although this value will repeat itself like this `1 - mens - 3`, `1 - shoes - 3`, `1 - black - 3` where `1` is the product id `mens`, `shoes` and `black` are the keywords and `3` is the keywords count. This way we can put a having clause like `having count(*) = TOT_COUNT` where `TOT_COUNT` is the repeating total count value. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do that by using this following method:

I created two new tables:

```
product_keywords
id | keyword | tot_kwds

product_ignore_keyword
id | keyword
```

- First I extract words from the search-source-string
- Next I use this query to get the matching records:

`select id, tot_kwds from product_keywords where keyword in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3') group by id having count(*) = tot_kwds`

- This way, I get the ids that have ALL the keywords present in the search-source-string. Let us name them `keyword-found-ids`
- Next I get the ids that are found in the ignore keywords map:

`select id from product_ignore_keywords where id in (keyword-found-ids) and keyword in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')`

- Now I get those ids that are found in keywords but also found in ignore keywords, say `ignore-keyword-found-ids`
- So my final result is this:

`keyword-found-ids - ignore-keyword-found-ids`

- I take the first id from this final result and that is the matching product we are looking for.

This method works for me fine!

Here is sample php code:

```
$arrW = getWordsFromString($searchString);

if ( !is_array($arrW) || count($arrW) == 0 )
    return 0;

$pids = array();
$sql = "select id, tot_kwds from product_keywords where keyword in ('".implode("', '", $arrW)."') group by id having count(*) = tot_kwds";
$res = db_query($sql);
while ( ($row = db_row($res)) )
    $pids[] = (int)$row['id'];

if ( count($pids) == 0 )
    return 0;

$nids = array();
$sql = "select id from product_ignore_keywords where id in (".implode(', ', $pids).") and keyword in ('".implode("', '", $arrW)."')";
$res = db_query($sql);
while ( ($row = db_row($res)) )
    $nids[] = (int)$row['id'];

$pids = array_diff($pids, $nids);

if ( count($pids) == 0 )
    return 0;

$finalId = (int)$pids[0];
```

I will wait for any suggestions to further optimize this answer. If there are none, then I will mark it as accepted answer.

Cheers